# Laravel route destroy return back issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have a step2 form which will store `Order` first in step1 then go to step2 page which the purpose is storing `Aircon`

When Click "trash icon" should go to route destroy but after `return back()`
Error: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

How to do correctly? passing `$order` in destroy ?

```
public function destroy(Aircon $aircon)
{
    $aircon->delete();
    return back();
}
```

```
public function store(Request $request, Order $order)
{
    $order = Order::find($order->id);

    $attributes = $this->validateAirCon();

    $order->aircons()->create($attributes);

    return view('pages.user.order-aircons.addAircon',compact('order'));
}
```

```
<form action="{{ route('aircon.store', $order) }}" method="post">
    @csrf

    {{--inputs... --}}
    
    <button type="submit">aircon.store</button>
</form>

@forelse ($order->aircons as $aircon)
    <table class="table">
        <th>Model Number</th>
            {{-- th.. --}}
        <tr>
            {{-- td... --}}
            <td>
                {{-- Delete Aircon --}}
                <form action="{{ route('aircon.destroy', $aircon) }}" method="post">
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @csrf
                    {{-- button submit --}}
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
@empty
    <h1>no data</h1>
@endforelse
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the route name:

```
public function destroy(Aircon $aircon)
{
    $aircon->delete();

    // Put the route name that you want to be redirected to that.
    return redirect()->route('YOUR_ROUTE_NAME');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

Use custom route to pass two parameters `Aircon` and `Order`

```
Route::delete('/aircon/delete/{aircon}/order{order}', [AirConController::class, 'delete'])->name('aircon.destroy');
```

```
public function delete(Aircon $aircon, Order $order)
{
    $aircon->delete();
    return view('pages.user.order-aircons.addAircon', compact('order'));
}
```

Comment: `$order` is already set from your function so `$order = ...` is useless and only makes another query.